# How do I properly setup a texture position using XNA/Monogame VertexPositionTexture on a circle

Tags: c#, textures, xna-4.0, geometry, trigonometry

I am using the following to create a circle using VertexPositionTexture:

```
public static ObjectData Circle(Vector2 origin, float radius, int slices)
{
    /// See below
}
```

The texture that is applied to it doesn't look right, it spirals out from the center. I have tried some other things but nothing does it how I want.  I would like for it to kind-of just fan around the circle, or start in the top-left end finish in the bottom-right. Basically wanting it to be easier to create textures for it.

I know that are MUCH easier ways to do this without using meshes, but that is not what I am trying to accomplish right now.

This is the code that ended up working thanks to Pinckerman:

```
 public static ObjectData Circle(Vector2 origin, float radius, int slices)
{
    VertexPositionTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionTexture[slices + 2];
    int[] indices = new int[slices * 3];

    float x = origin.X;
    float y = origin.Y;

    float deltaRad = MathHelper.ToRadians(360) / slices;
    float delta = 0;

    float thetaInc = (((float)Math.PI * 2) / vertices.Length);

    vertices[0] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(x, y, 0), new Vector2(.5f, .5f));
    float sliceSize = 1f / slices;

    for (int i = 1; i < slices + 2; i++)
    {
        float newX = (float)Math.Cos(delta) * radius + x;
        float newY = (float)Math.Sin(delta) * radius + y;

        float textX = 0.5f + ((radius * (float)Math.Cos(delta)) / (radius * 2));
        float textY = 0.5f + ((radius * (float)Math.Sin(delta)) /(radius * 2));

        vertices[i] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(newX, newY, 0), new Vector2(textX, textY));

        delta += deltaRad;
    }

    indices[0] = 0;
    indices[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < slices; i++)
    {
        indices[3 * i] = 0;
        indices[(3 * i) + 1] = i + 1;
        indices[(3 * i) + 2] = i + 2;
    }

    ObjectData thisData = new ObjectData()
    {
        Vertices = vertices,
        Indices = indices
    };
    return thisData;
}

public static ObjectData Ellipse()
{
    ObjectData thisData = new ObjectData()
    {
    };
    return thisData;
}
```

`ObjectData` is just a structure that contains an array of vertices & an array of indices.

Hope this helps others that may be trying to accomplish something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a spiral because you've set the upper-left point for the texture `Vector2(0,0)` in the center of your "circle" and it's wrong. You need to set it on the top-left vertex of the top-left slice of you circle, because 0,0 of your UV map is the upper left corner of your texture.

I think you need to set (0.5, 0) for the upper vertex, (1, 0.5) for the right, (0.5, 1) for the lower and (0, 0.5) for the left, or something like this, and for the others use some trigonometry.
The center of your circle has to be `Vector2(0.5, 0.5)`.

Regarding the trigonometry, I think you should do something like this.
The center of your circle has UV value of `Vector2(0.5, 0.5)`, and for the others (supposing the second point of the sequence is just right to the center, having UV value of `Vector2(1, 0.5)`) try something like this:

```
vertices[i] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(newX, newY, 0), new Vector2(0.5f + radius * (float)Math.Cos(delta), 0.5f - radius * (float)Math.Sin(delta)));
```

I've just edited your third line in the for-loop. This should give you the UV coordinates you need for each point. I hope so.

Comment: thanks, I've tried all sorts of stuff to get it right. I suppose it the trigonometry that I am actually asking about.

Comment: Do you need help about the trigonometry or can you do it yourself?

Comment: That's where I am getting stuck at, the trig part. I guess I should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: I've added some info in the answer above.

Comment: that helps a bit; in fact it;s the closest I have gotten and I may not be able to get any farther.  I had to adjust it to this: `float textX = 0.5f + (radius * (float)Math.Cos(delta)/100f);
                float textY = 0.5f + (radius * (float)Math.Sin(delta)/100f);`   What ends up happening is it makes a square in the middle of the circle, then uses the same pixels from the edge of the square to the edge of the circle.

Comment: I can't understand why you had to adjust it adding that division. So what's the problem now? I don't get it. If you can add a picture it can help.

Comment: Dividing it by 100 was part of the issue. You comment above got me trying some other stuff and I found that I should have been dividing by the radius * 2.  Once I did that it looks perfect.